Why is my boostrap button stretching down when clicked on?
I have a bootstrap login page component that I am using for a react project. However, I have noticed that whenever I click on the login button, it stretches all the way down and I am not sure why it is doing so every time it is clicked. Here is the component I got from the bootstrap website:
import React from 'react';
import {
  MDBContainer,
  MDBInput,
  MDBCheckbox,
  MDBBtn,
  MDBIcon
}
from 'mdb-react-ui-kit';

function App() {
  return (
    <MDBContainer className="p-3 my-5 d-flex flex-column w-50">

      <MDBInput wrapperClass='mb-4' label='Email address' id='form1' type='email'/>
      <MDBInput wrapperClass='mb-4' label='Password' id='form2' type='password'/>

      <div className="d-flex justify-content-between mx-3 mb-4">
        <MDBCheckbox name='flexCheck' value='' id='flexCheckDefault' label='Remember me' />
        <a href="!#">Forgot password?</a>
      </div>

      <MDBBtn className="mb-4">Sign in</MDBBtn>

      <div className="text-center">
        <p>Not a member? <a href="#!">Register</a></p>
        <p>or sign up with:</p>

        <div className='d-flex justify-content-between mx-auto' style={{width: '40%'}}>
          <MDBBtn tag='a' color='none' className='m-1' style={{ color: '#1266f1' }}>
            <MDBIcon fab icon='facebook-f' size="sm"/>
          </MDBBtn>

          <MDBBtn tag='a' color='none' className='m-1' style={{ color: '#1266f1' }}>
            <MDBIcon fab icon='twitter' size="sm"/>
          </MDBBtn>

          <MDBBtn tag='a' color='none' className='m-1' style={{ color: '#1266f1' }}>
            <MDBIcon fab icon='google' size="sm"/>
          </MDBBtn>

          <MDBBtn tag='a' color='none' className='m-1' style={{ color: '#1266f1' }}>
            <MDBIcon fab icon='github' size="sm"/>
          </MDBBtn>

        </div>
      </div>

    </MDBContainer>
  );
}

export default App;

I have tried looking at the code to see where clicking the button is causing it to stretch but I cannot seem to find this. Any help would be appreciated.

You need to import the CSS import 'mdb-react-ui-kit/dist/css/mdb.min.css';
